# PubNub keychain on osx in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pubnub

How do I setup the pubnub cocoa objective-c client api to NOT store anything on the keychain? Is it possible to store the keys on the Application Support folder instead? When I am using XCode the keychain messagebox modal appears three times even when I press the 'Always Allow' button. It stops for a while but then after a few minutes it asks me again the same way again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked on my side and it really requested password for each read from Keychain. Tried to find solution and after system reboot, tried again - it requested for password one or three times and then just keep working. As for now, there is no option to configure client without Keychain usage. 
Earlier Keychain worked like well after single password input. Looks like one of system updates broke how system interact with developed applications.
Maybe it is somehow related to security and checking "*Automatically manage signing*" and specifying proper profiles will help you (I'm unable to check this, since Keychain gives me access w/o asking password now since I marked *awlays*).

Keychain used to store few fields: publish sequence number, uuid,  and push token. It had been added to Keychain to survive application re-install.
We will review macOS Keychain usage and if it will be allowed, we will add ability to use file-based data storage (maybe by default for macOS).